which one best one 1.credentials.refreshIfExpired() vs 2.credentials.refresh() in firebase FCM HTTP v1
We know that access Token expiry was one hour, can i use refreshIfExpired() will it impact performance
if i create the access Token for first time to send it to REST Call, will create the token from service_account_key.json
